# Converting tbl_df to dataframe produces error

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I'm getting error in converting a tbl_df in one system and not the other. For example, here is the error.

```
library ( dplyr)
d<- data.frame (type=c("rna","rna","rna"), value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (type=c("dna","dna"), value = c(20,30) )
d3 <- data.frame (type=c("protein","protein","protein"), value = c(-9.6,300, 1000) )
df <- rbind (d,d2,d3)

df %>% 
    group_by(type) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(if(any(. < 0)) max(.) else mean(.))) %>% data.frame() -> df2
```

This will produce the error:

> "Error in as_regular_df(x) : could not find function "as_regular_df"

**The weird thing is that on a diffrent system with the sample dplyr and tibble package there is no error.**  Does anyone know a workaround? Thanks. 
Below is the session info on the system that has the error.

```
  attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] tibble_2.1.3 dplyr_0.8.3 

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       rstudioapi_0.7   bindr_0.1.1      magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1 lattice_0.20-35  R6_2.4.0        
    [10] rlang_0.4.0      fansi_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0    tools_3.4.0      grid_3.4.0       gtable_0.3.0     utf8_1.1.4       cli_1.1.0        lazyeval_0.2.2  
    [19] assertthat_0.2.1 crayon_1.3.4     Matrix_1.2-14    bindrcpp_0.2.2   purrr_0.3.2      ggplot2_3.2.1    vctrs_0.2.0      zeallot_0.1.0    glue_1.3.1      
    [28] stringi_1.4.3    compiler_3.4.0   pillar_1.4.2     backports_1.1.4  scales_1.0.0     pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Comment: Also works fine here with a soft deprication of funs() in dplyr. Is your R version up to date?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise_all(~(if(any(. < 0)) max(.) else mean(.))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

df2

     type value
1     rna     2
2     dna    25
3 protein  1000
```